# Scrapy: Scraping Links / Anchors + Putting 1 Per Row Next to Other On-Page Element (Title Tags / H1 Tags / etc...)

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to create a script that'd scrape information from various websites and export it to a CSV in a specified format.

I've been able to get everything to work, except it's not in the ideal format.

Right now, it's a single row per page, and all of the links and link anchor text is nested within a circle list - which create a long list within a single cell within Excel.

Ideally, what i'm trying to accomplish is to separate the lists to make them individual rows (orange in attached image) next duplicated versions of the single data points (grey in attached image).

Any help would be appreciated!!

[image]

``

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import Rule, CrawlSpider


class InseevSpiderSpider(scrapy.spiders.CrawlSpider):
    name = 'ExampleScraper'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.example.com/']
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow_domains=[
             'example.com']), follow=True, callback="parse_item"),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(deny=('.png', ))),

    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        address = response.url
        count_address = len(address)
        content_type = response.headers['Content-Type']
        status_code = response.status
        title = response.xpath("//title/text()").extract()
        count_title = len(title[0])
        description = response.xpath(
            "//meta[@name='description']/@content").extract_first()
        if description:
            count_description = len(description)
        else:
            count_description = 0
        keywords = response.xpath(
            "//meta[@name='keywords']/@content").extract_first()
        h1 = response.xpath('//h1//text()').extract_first()
        h2 = response.xpath('//h2//text()').extract_first()
        robot = response.xpath(
            "//meta[@name='robots']/@content").extract_first()
        download_time = response.meta['download_latency']
        link_anchor = response.xpath("//a/text()").extract()
        link_href = response.xpath("//a/@href").extract()

        yield {
            'Address': address,
            'Address count': count_address,
            'Content Type': content_type,
            'Status code': status_code,
            'Title': title,
            'Title count': count_title,
            'Meta description': description,
            'Meta description count': count_description,
            'Meta keywords': keywords,
            'H1': h1,
            'H2': h2,
            'Robot': robot,
            'Download time': download_time,
            "Link Anchor": link_anchor,
            "Link @href": link_href
        }
```

``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is writing a loop and yielding multiple items:

```py
for anchor, href in zip(link_anchor, link_href):
    yield {
        ...
        "Link Anchor": anchor,
        "Link @href": href
    }
```